# Cursorfetch:The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2000, database-cursor

```
declare @id int
declare @empid int
set @id = 0
declare @schedindate datetime
declare @ss nvarchar(100)
declare @indice nvarchar(2)
declare @FromDate datetime
declare @ToDate datetime
declare @TimeInR datetime
declare @TimeOutR datetime
set @FromDate = '2009-01-14'
set @ToDate = '2010-01-30'

Declare cc cursor for select distinct empid from ta_timecard where schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
open cc
fetch next from cc into @empid
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    set @id = @id + 1
    insert into ta_MonthlyAttendance (ID, EmpID) values (@id, @empid)

    declare cc2 cursor for select distinct schedindate, TimeInR, TimeOutR from ta_timecard where empid = @empid and schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
    open cc2
    fetch next from cc2 into @schedindate, @TimeInR
    while (@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin

        set @indice = cast(datediff(day, @fromdate, @schedindate) as nvarchar(4))
        set @TimeInR = (select TOP 1 ta_TimeCard.TimeInR from ta_TimeCard where (@schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate) and EmpID=@empid)
        set @schedindate = (select TOP 1 ta_TimeCard.SchedInDate from ta_TimeCard where (@schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate) and empid=@empid)
        set @ss = 'update ta_MonthlyAttendance set NOD ' + @indice  + ' = + dbo.ta_dayofweek('+ char(39) + convert(nvarchar(50), @schedindate, 102) + char(39) +' ) , TimeInR ' + @indice + ' =  + @TimeInR + where empid = ' + cast(@empid as nvarchar(20))
        execute sp_executesql @ss
        fetch next from cc2 into @schedindate, @TimeInR
end
close cc2
deallocate cc2
fetch next from cc into @empid
end
close cc
Deallocate cc
```

this code gives error in the line "fetch next from cc2 into @schedindate, @TimeInR"

where's my fault? I can't find it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @empid INT
    , @schedindate DATETIME
    , @ss NVARCHAR(100)
    , @indice NVARCHAR(2)
    , @FromDate DATETIME
    , @ToDate DATETIME
    , @TimeInR DATETIME
    , @TimeOutR DATETIME

SELECT 
      @FromDate = '20090114'
    , @ToDate = '20100130'

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      schedindate DATETIME
    , TimeInR VARCHAR(10)
    , TimeOutR VARCHAR(10)
    , empid INT
)
INSERT INTO @temp (schedindate, TimeInR, TimeOutR, empid)
SELECT DISTINCT
      schedindate
    , TimeInR
    , TimeOutR
    , empid 
FROM dbo.ta_timecard
WHERE schedindate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

DECLARE @ids TABLE(id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), emp BIGINT)
INSERT INTO @ids (emp)
SELECT DISTINCT empid
FROM @temp

INSERT INTO dbo.ta_MonthlyAttendance(id, EmpID)
SELECT id, emp
FROM @ids

DECLARE cc CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT empid
    FROM @temp

OPEN cc
FETCH NEXT FROM cc INTO @empid

WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0) BEGIN

    SELECT
          @indice = CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, @fromdate, t.SchedInDate) AS NVARCHAR(4))
        , @TimeInR = t.TimeInR
        , @schedindate = t.SchedInDate
    FROM @temp t
    WHERE empid = @empid

    SELECT @ss = 'update ta_MonthlyAttendance set NOD ' + @indice 
        + ' = + dbo.ta_dayofweek(' + CHAR(39) 
        + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @schedindate, 102) + CHAR(39) + ' ) , TimeInR ' 
        + @indice + ' = ' + @TimeInR + ' where empid = ' + CAST(@empid AS NVARCHAR(20))

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @ss

    FETCH NEXT FROM cc INTO @empid

END

CLOSE cc
DEALLOCATE cc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i just can't use Row_Number() do you have any idea why ?

Comment: What's your SQL Server version?

Comment: sql server 2000, it doesn't exist in this version

Comment: Why? What have you changed to avoid the error? There look to have been lots of stylistic changes such as grouping declare statements, that only distract from the relevant fix.

Answer (score 6):

```
declare cc2 cursor for 
   select distinct schedindate, TimeInR, TimeOutR 
   from ta_timecard where empid = @empid 
    and schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
    open cc2
    fetch next from cc2 into @schedindate, @TimeInR
```

You are selecting `schedindate, TimeInR, TimeOutR` but the into statement has only `@schedindate, @TimeInR`

Comment: oh i didn't see it thank You so much.. I'm just gonna ask one more thing, now i'm, getting a list of errors where the number 0 increment 1 number in every error: Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '0'.