# Cursorfetch :The number of variables must match that of selected columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I have checked over this several times. The column count matches but it still getting an error belows :

> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must
>   match that of selected columns.

I know this question has been asked many times, but I still get stuck. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @prev_s_Case CHAR(4)= null,@prev_startDate DATETIME= null,@prev_endDate DATETIME= null, @prev_ukey INT= null, @cur_s_Case CHAR(4), @cur_startDate DATETIME, @cur_endDate DATETIME, @cur_ukey INT, @result varchar(500);

DECLARE THE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT  s_Case, startDate, endDate, ukey FROM   #TEMP
ORDER BY s_Case

BEGIN
OPEN THE_CURSOR;

FETCH NEXT FROM THE_CURSOR 
INTO @cur_s_Case, @cur_startDate, @cur_endDate, @cur_ukey

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    SELECT s_Case, startDate, endDate, ukey  
    FROM #TEMP

    IF (    (@prev_s_Case = @cur_s_Case))
    BEGIN
        IF ((@cur_startDate BETWEEN @prev_startDate AND @prev_endDate) AND (@cur_endDate >= @prev_endDate))
        BEGIN
            SET @result = CASE WHEN @result = '' THEN str(@prev_ukey)
                            ELSE @result + ','+ str(@prev_ukey) END
        END
        ELSE IF ((@cur_startDate BETWEEN @prev_startDate AND @prev_endDate)
                AND (@cur_endDate < @prev_endDate))
        BEGIN
            SET @result = CASE WHEN @result = '' THEN str(@cur_ukey)
                            ELSE @result + ','+ str(@cur_ukey) END
        END
    END

    SET @prev_s_Case= @cur_s_Case;
    SET @prev_startDate = @cur_startDate;
    SET @prev_endDate = @cur_endDate;
    SET @prev_ukey = @cur_ukey;

    FETCH NEXT FROM THE_CURSOR 
    INTO @cur_s_Case,@cur_startDate,@cur_endDate,@cur_ukey

    print @result
CLOSE THE_CURSOR;

DEALLOCATE THE_CURSOR;
END
```

Comment: Cursors should usually be avoided whenever possible. Perhaps if you posted sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into statements) and desired results, we can come up with a better way to get the result you want.

Comment: Just tried your code snippet and it works fine for me. Assuming your `#TEMP` table is created as per the variable definition.

Comment: Parses ok but then goes into an infinite loop (I added a dummy temp table with a single row to test this).  The WHILE clause should have a BEGIN and END indicating what should happen in the loop - otherwise it only does the statement immediatly following the WHILE statement and doesn't get more rows from the cursor.

Comment: I have checked it and you were right. It works fine but goes into an infinite loop @j.f.sebastian . Thank you for recheck it. It helps a lot

Comment: @natadecoco this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786065/4092887) might help -  it solved the problem I was facing.